# Parameters can't be passed to a url using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have defined the parameters to pass to rapidAPI using `Alamofire`, but I've got an error.

I followed everything they said in the API documentation. If I put the full URL into a string it works fine, but when I pass as a parameter it doesn't

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let CURRENT_BR_LEAGUE_URL = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let params = ["country_name" : "england", "season" : "2018"]

        getLeague(url: CURRENT_BR_LEAGUE_URL, parameters: params)
    }

    func getHeaders() -> [String : String] {
        let headers = [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ]
        return headers
    }

    func getLeague (url : String, parameters : [String : String]) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: getHeaders()).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                let leagueJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(leagueJSON)
                print()
            }
            else {

            }

        }
    }


}
```

It throws a "wrong country" error. If I use full URL 
`let CURRENT_BR_LEAGUE_URL = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/england/2018"` it works fine.

If I use `"https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/"`
and set the parameters

```
let params = ["country_name" : "england", "season" : "2018"]
```

it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I looked now into RapidApi documentation for API-Football, you don't need the parameters. You just need to construct the URL from different parts and then make a GET request.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let MAIN_URL = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getLeague(for: "england", year: 2018)
    }

    func getHeaders() -> [String : String] {
        let headers = [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ]
        return headers
    }

    func getLeague (for country : String, year: Int) {

        let url = MAIN_URL + country + "/\(year)/"

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: getHeaders()).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                let leagueJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(leagueJSON)
                print()
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Your Code, you are making a get request. So you have to pass the params bind with your base URL. Please try the below code hopefully it will work for you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let CURRENT_BR_LEAGUE_URL = "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/leagues/country/%@/%@"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let params = ["country_name" : "england", "season" : "2018"]

        let urlString =  String(format: CURRENT_BR_LEAGUE_URL, params["country_name"],params["season"])

        getLeague(url: urlString, parameters: nil)
    }

    func getHeaders() -> [String : String] {
        let headers = [
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ]
        return headers
    }

    func getLeague (url : String, parameters : [String : String]?) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: getHeaders()).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {

                let leagueJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(leagueJSON)
                print()
            }
            else {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something here. urlString is URL and you accept String - isn't that producing error : Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String' ?

Comment: Also, params["anything"] will require ! at the end